# In Javascript DOM, is it ok to set focus to an item and later render the item in the document?

Tags: javascript, dom, focus

For example:

```
// build the form
var form = document.createElement('form');
var item = document.createElement('item');
form.appendChild(item);

// item is where we want our future focus
item.focus();
....

// render the form
document.getElementById('id').appendChild( form );
```

Is this legal? Will focus be on `item` once rendered?

This is important because I am dealing with a library that expects me to pass a built form that it will then place on the page. I would like to ensure proper focus when the form has been rendered.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only focus on an element that exists in the page.

You can however keep the reference to the object, and use it to set focus once it has been added to the page.